# Whats wrong with my mySQL_query?

Tags: php, mysql

When I use the query below, it only updates if the new value is shorter than what was originally there, anyone know why this is?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET first_name='$first_name',
              last_name='$last_name',
              email='$email',
              bio='$bio' WHERE id='$id'");

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['update-profile'])){
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $bio = $_POST['bio']; 

        if(empty($bio) || empty($first_name) || empty($last_name) || empty($email)){
            echo 'Please fill in all fields!';
        } else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', email='$email', bio='$bio' WHERE id='$id'");
            echo "Profile Updated";
            header('location: pond.php');
        }

    }
?>
            First Name: <br /><input type="text" name="first_name"></input><br /><br />
            Last Name: <br /><input type="text" name="last_name"></input><br /><br />
            Email Address: <br /><input type="email" name="email"></input><br /><br />
            Bio: <br /><input type="text" name="bio"></input><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Update Profile" name="update-profile">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show me your table creation script, please.

Comment: Well, two things I see: 1. You're using deprecated `mysql_*` function. 2. You're open to SQL injection.

Comment: *shorter* character length? or ?

Comment: Likely not a problem with your query but the variables you're passing it

Comment: You should stop using the [original MySQL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) for it is deprecated and unsafe. Move to newer extensions like [mysqli](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RobertRozas - Is this of any help? http://pastebin.com/sQBsW6p0

Comment: i think the issue is not with your query syntax, i think it's related to the field properties in the table!,
can you please turn errors display on and try to get the output when you execute unsuccessful query?

Comment: @MaveRick - It isn't giving any errors

Comment: I think the same @MaveRick ....that's why i ask for the table creation script

Comment: ok try to execute the same unsuccessful query using `phpmyadmin` and give us the results please

Comment: You can't use `echo` and then `header()`.

Comment: @ironcito you are right but this issue has nothing to do with his issue

Answer (score 1):

As @Maverick is telling you. Test the sentence in PHPMyAdmin.

The easiest way to test your SQL statements is to use a variable for it, eg:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name='".$first_name."', last_name='".$last_name."', email='".$email."', bio='".$bio."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

and then use `mysql_query($sql);` afterwards.

It seems like more code, but the trick here is that you can comment out your `header()`, insert an echo in front of the `$sql` variable to print it to the screen (when you run the file again), copy the printed string into `PHPMyAdmin` and see if there should be any MySQL errors that aren't being caught by PHP. Also you will quickly discover if there are any mis

Also I would look into MySQLi, it will give you both more features when working with MySQL and give you more abilities to secure your queries.

Comment: What's at the end of "Also you will quickly discover if there are any mis . . ."   "mistakes"?

Comment: Oh sorry about that
It was:
Also you will quickly discover if there are any mistakes in that query string eg. missing pings ' ' in strings.